# python: if-else on elements of list in one line ternary operator

Tags: python, ternary-operator

I was going through a code of tokenizing a tweet in python when I encountered the following piece of code. Note that `tokens_re` and `emoticons_re` are regex objects. Since `tokenize(s)` returns a list therefore `tokens` is a list. I am kind of new to python and I am not sure is the if-else running on the elements of list. The [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#Python) as mentioned doesnt have the same syntax.

```
def tokenize(s):
    return tokens_re.findall(s)

def preprocess(s, lowercase=False):
    tokens = tokenize(s)
    if lowercase:
        tokens = [token if emoticon_re.search(token) else token.lower() for token in tokens]
    return tokens
```

Comment: I do not get what the question is.

Comment: how is he using the ternary operator on every element of the list in the given code? I am not able to understand how did he iterate every element of the list in the if block though he uses a for loop in else block

Comment: It works fine. In the _list comprehension_ `token` loops over `tokens`, and for each value of `token` we have a ternary expression, the result of which is stored on the resulting list. Imagine parentheses around the termary.

Comment: @AndrasDeak he used a for loop in the else statement but not used any loop in the if statement how did he iterate over the list in the if statement?

Comment: @kartikeykant18: no the `for` is part of the list comprehension. The ternary operator has precedence over that.

Comment: It can't be read in any other meaningful way, there's no ambiguity here and precedence is meaningless @Willem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ternary operator **has the same syntax**:

```py
[(token if emoticon_re.search(token) else token.lower()) for token in tokens]
#^              ternary operator expression            ^
```

So the **`for` is *not* part of the `else` part of the ternary operator**. The `for` is part of the *list comprehension* itself.

The ternary operator is written in boldface here. In the C/C++/C#/Java, we would have written it as:

```java
// Java equivalent
emoticon_re.search(token) ? token : token.lower()
```

So basically for every item in the list, it will apply the ternary operator. The list comprehension is equivalent to:

```py
# list comprehension is equivalent to:
tmp = []
for token in tokens:
    if emoticon_re.search(token):
        tmp.append(token)
    else:
        tmp.append(token.lower())
tokens = tmp
```

Answer (score 3):

Formatted comment:

```
tokens = [token if emoticon_re.search(token) else token.lower() for token in tokens]
```

is equivalent to

```
tokens = [(token if emoticon_re.search(token) else token.lower()) for token in tokens]
```

Comment: Can we write this without for loop, i.e. just using an if condition to put a single default value in the list?.  I'm getting syntax errors this way.

Comment: @y_159 I don't understand what you mean. The whole point of a list comprehension is to loop over something to build a list. There are two syntax elements combined here: a list comprehension (`[foo for bar in baz]`) and a conditional expression (`foo if bar else baz`). If you just need a single value in a list depending on a condition, you can do `[foo if bar else baz]`. If `bar` is truthy, you'll get `[foo]`, otherwise you'll get `[baz]`. Does this answer your question?

Comment: yes it does. but can we omit `else` here. I was getting syntax error in that case.  instead of `baz` i wanted an empty list. My question got answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72681789

Comment: @y_159 I see. Yes, the conditional expression must have an else part. You got some pretty terrible answers there; ignore the list comprehension suggestions. Go for `['True'] if condition else []`. Or perhaps even better: `result = []; of condition: result.append('True')`.

Comment: yes i followed the first one only, seems more pythonic and reasonable way to go with. btw `result = []; of condition: result.append('True')` expression got some c/c++ style syntax.

Comment: @y_159 sorry, that was a typo. I meant `if condition: ...` and of course spelled out on a different line. I just can't put linefeeds in comments. Anyway, it's all resolved now.