# if condition inside list comprehension without an iterable to put a default value

Tags: python

```
>>> x = 7
>>> res = [ 'True' if x > 1 and x < 5 ]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    res = [ 'True' if x > 1 and x < 5 ]
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> res = [ 'True' if x > 1 and x < 5 else 'False']
['False']
```

I want to put a default value inside the `res` list based on some condition and keep the list empty otherwise. So with what syntax/value should I replace `False` with to keep the list empty in case the condition fails.

I can do it in other ways but this seems like a single line syntax to create a list and initialize a value to it. I found other posts but everywhere a for loop/iterable is used inside the list comprehension which is not relevant in this case.

Comment: Do you really want the *string* `'True'`? If the boolean is sufficient (or, in fact, _preferred_), couldn't you just omit the `if` entirely? `res = x > 1 and x < 5` (or more succinctly: `res = 1 < x < 5`)

Comment: If so, Python does allow a sort of ternary syntax. `a if pred else b` is equivalent to `pred ? a : b` in other languages. `"this" if 1 < x < 5 else "that"`, for instance.

Comment: the example i presented is a formulated one. I'm using it sort of checking keys inside an object and then putting the value of nested key to a list . just wanted the list to be empty in case the key doesn't exist along with some other `and`  condition.

Comment: Ah perhaps you want `dict.get` then? `dict.get{"outer_key", {}).get("inner_key", None)` or etc?

Comment: this will put 'None' inside the list. list will not be empty then.

Comment: Trying to parse out what your example is versus what your actual need is :)

Comment: This does smack of an X/Y problem though. Since you haven't actually asked your _real_ question, it's hard to tell whether any of the answers actually make your code better or if they just help you do the wrong thing :)

Comment: @AdamSmith `lst = [ 'any_string' if 'inner_key' in dict['outer_key'] and dict['outer_key']['inner_key']['inner_key2'] > 0 ]`  in case inner_key2 value is 0  then the `lst` should be initialised as empty. this was the original requirement, but i was getting syntax error so tried to reproduce it on the python terminal as shown in the post with simple example, looks like can't use an only `if` without a generator, need to combine with an else otherwise. But in else what do i write to make the list as empty, the problem came down to that. Accepted answer's first answer didn't strike me :).

Comment: I'm just confused why you're building a list with either one or zero values in it. The datatype seems wrong for the problem at hand.

Comment: @AdamSmith so that i can extend it later. Following code appends more values to it based on some conditions. otherwise it will return a single/zero element list to UI/FE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't a list comprehension, because you don't have a generator expression inside the `[]`; the conditional should therefore go *outside* the `[]` so that the two options are just two different literals:

```
res = ['True'] if 1 < x < 5 else []
```

If for some reason you're really hung up on putting that `if` inside the brackets, you can turn it into a (pointless) list comprehension by creating an iteration over one element:

```
res = ['True' for _ in "_" if 1 < x < 5]
```

Comment: thanks. feeling dumb. I'll wait for other solutions before accepting it.  can you explain the working of second solution?

Comment: It's an iteration over one element.  The actual content of the string doesn't matter, just that it's an iterable object with one item; you could also use `range(1)` or `(x,)` or `{'Flipping Hades Terwilliger'}` and it would work the same way.  If you used an iterable with more than one item, you'd get that many `'True'`s if the condition is met.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can do this way as well

```
[ r for r in [x] if 1 < x < 5 ]
```